# Button with if condition

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-button

I am new to Android, and i am trying to make a one button open 2 activities but is not working for me.
for ex:
on `Mainacitivity`, there is `btn_mathematics` and `btn_physics` open the same activity (`Main2acitivity`) and find `btn_semester1` and `btn_semester2`, each button will open 2 other activities for the semester modules.

If the user on Mainacitivity clicked on:
`btn_mathematics` ---> `btn_semester1`---> will have `ModulesMAT`
and if clicked on the btn_semester1 same button: 
`btn_physics` ---> `btn_semester1` ---> will have `ModulesPHY` .

**MainActivity XML:**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_mathematics"
    android:onClick="btn_mathematics"
    android:text="@string/btn_mathematics/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_physics"
    android:onClick="btn_physics"
    android:text="@string/btn_physics"/>
```

**Main2Activity XML:**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_semester1"
    android:onClick="btn_semester1"
    android:text="@string/btn_semester1"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_semester2"
    android:onClick="btn_s2"
    android:text="@string/btn_semester2"/>
```

I guess that no need to add xml for ModulesMAT and ModulesPHY, its pretty similar to the the others.

and now the java code:

**MainActivity.java:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void btn_mathematics (View v)  {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    `public void btn_physics (View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


}
```

**Main2Activity.java:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
}



public void btn_semester1 (View v)
{
    Intent i = getIntent();
    String id = i.getStringExtra("id");
    if(id == "btn_mathematics")
    {
         i = new Intent(this, ModulesMAT.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    else if (id == "btn_physics")
    {
         i = new Intent(this, ModulesPHY.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

}


public void btn_semester2 (View v)
{
    Intent i = getIntent();
    String id = i.getStringExtra("id");
    if(id == "btn_mathematics")
    {
        i = new Intent(this, ModulesMAT2.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    else if (id == "btn_physics")
    {
        i = new Intent(this, ModulesPHY2.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

Comment: You can pass data between activities through the `Intent`. Here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/2091482/1552587

Comment: Thank you for comment, can i have an example on my code?

Answer (score 1):

In MainActivity you can pass the id for recognizing into Main2Activity.
**MainActivity**

```
   public void btn_mathematics (View v)  {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("id","Math");
        intent.putExtra(bundle);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

public void btn_physics (View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("id","Physics");
    intent.putExtra(bundle);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

**Main2Activity**

```
String id;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    id= bundle.getString("id");
}

public void btn_semester1 (View v)
{
    if(id == "Math")
    {
        i = new Intent(this, ModulesMAT2.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    else if (id == "Physics")
    {
        i = new Intent(this, ModulesPHY2.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

}


public void btn_semester2 (View v)
{
    if(id == "Math")
    {
        i = new Intent(this, ModulesMAT2.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    else if (id == "Physics")
    {
        i = new Intent(this, ModulesPHY2.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

Comment: You should use `...equals(...)` to compare `String`s instead of `==`

Comment: You helped me man, thank you so much,
just one little problem on my second activity, with your code:

  `if(id == "Math")
    {
        i = new Intent(this, ModulesMAT2.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    else if (id == "Physics")
    {
        i = new Intent(this, ModulesPHY2.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

}`

 i am having 
(cannot resolve symbole 'i')

Comment: Just add Intent before each i. Like: Intent i = new Intent (this, ModulesMat2.class);